# Fill all four quadrants of a circle with different colors

Tags: tikz-pgf

Question: Here i am trying to fill quadrants of a circle with different colors, i have started with scope but didn't get success. How can i achieve this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,scale=.9,x=1cm,y=1cm]
    \begin{axis}[
    x=1cm,y=1cm,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={stealth-stealth},
    xmin=-5,
    xmax=5,
    ymin=-5,
    ymax=5.0,
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick=\empty,]
    \draw [line width=0.8pt,color=black] (0,0) circle (3cm);
    %Fill color
    \begin{scope}
    \fill[orange] (3,0) rectangle (0,3);
    \end{scope}
    %Labelling of endpoints and curve
    \draw[color=black] (-3.0,3.0) node {$x^2+y^2=9$};
    \draw [fill=black] (0,0) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw[color=black] (0.8,-0.6) node {$O(0 , 0)$};
    \draw [fill=black] (3,0) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw[color=black] (3.8,0.4) node {$A(3 , 0)$};
    \draw [fill=black] (0,3) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw[color=black] (0.70,3.40) node {$B(0 ,3)$};
    \draw [fill=black] (-3,0) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw[color=black] (-4.0,0.30) node {$C(-3 , 0)$};
    \draw [fill=black] (0,-3) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw[color=black] (1,-3.40) node {$D(0 , -3)$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Tikz` allows you to cut the frame *(paper)* on which you draw with the `clip` operation. All drawings made **after** the cutting **only** appear in the **cut area**.

Here, it is enough to cut before coloring.

```
\clip (0,0)circle (3cm);
%Fill color
\begin{scope}
\fill[orange] (3,0) rectangle (0,3);
\fill[blue] (-3,0) rectangle (0,3);
 \fill[green] (-3,0) rectangle (0,-3);
\fill[pink] (3,0) rectangle (0,-3);
\end{scope}
```

You will notice that this overwrites the black discs marking points A, B, C and D.

[image: clip]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,scale=.9,x=1cm,y=1cm]
    \begin{axis}[
    x=1cm,y=1cm,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={stealth-stealth},
    xmin=-5,
    xmax=5,
    ymin=-5,
    ymax=5.0,
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick=\empty,]
    \draw [line width=0.8pt,color=black] (0,0) circle (3cm);

    %Labelling of endpoints and curve
    \draw[color=black] (-3.0,3.0) node {$x^2+y^2=9$};
    \draw [fill=black] (0,0) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw[color=black] (0.8,-0.6) node {$O(0 , 0)$};
    \draw [fill=black] (3,0) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw[color=black] (3.8,0.4) node {$A(3 , 0)$};
    \draw [fill=black] (0,3) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw[color=black] (0.70,3.40) node {$B(0 ,3)$};
    \draw [fill=black] (-3,0) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw[color=black] (-4.0,0.30) node {$C(-3 , 0)$};
    \draw [fill=black] (0,-3) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw[color=black] (1,-3.40) node {$D(0 , -3)$};
    \clip (0,0)circle (3cm);
    %Fill color
    \begin{scope}
    \fill[orange] (3,0) rectangle (0,3);
    \fill[blue] (-3,0) rectangle (0,3);
     \fill[green] (-3,0) rectangle (0,-3);
    \fill[pink] (3,0) rectangle (0,-3);
    \end{scope}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Edit:

To avoid this problem, it is enough to perform the cutting within a scope environment. This allows you to continue drawing on the entire frame after leaving this scope.

### Edit 2: more explanations

The scope environment creates a subset of the drawing, i.e. it delimits a part of the drawing.

So there are now **two parts** in the drawing (frame):

- what is inside the scope environment;
- everything on the outside.

By creating a scope environment and cutting it into a circle, tikz is asked to limit the coloring within this circle.

Once out of this environment, we draw again on the whole page (frame).

```
    \begin{scope}% clip (cut) limited to this scope (view)
    \clip (0,0)circle (3cm);
    \fill[orange] (3,0) rectangle (0,3);
    \fill[blue] (-3,0) rectangle (0,3);
     \fill[green] (-3,0) rectangle (0,-3);
    \fill[pink] (3,0) rectangle (0,-3);
    \end{scope}% exit from the view, return to the drawing on the whole frame
```

[image: clip]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,scale=.9,x=1cm,y=1cm]
    \begin{axis}[
    x=1cm,y=1cm,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={stealth-stealth},
    xmin=-5,
    xmax=5,
    ymin=-5,
    ymax=5.0,
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick=\empty,]
    \draw [line width=0.8pt,color=black] (0,0) circle (3cm);
    %Fill color
    \begin{scope}
    \clip (0,0)circle (3cm);
    \fill[orange] (3,0) rectangle (0,3);
    \fill[blue] (-3,0) rectangle (0,3);
     \fill[green] (-3,0) rectangle (0,-3);
    \fill[pink] (3,0) rectangle (0,-3);
    \end{scope}
    %Labelling of endpoints and curve
    \draw[color=black] (-3.0,3.0) node {$x^2+y^2=9$};
    \draw [fill=black] (0,0) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw[color=black] (0.8,-0.6) node {$O(0 , 0)$};
    \draw [fill=black] (3,0) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw[color=black] (3.8,0.4) node {$A(3 , 0)$};
    \draw [fill=black] (0,3) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw[color=black] (0.70,3.40) node {$B(0 ,3)$};
    \draw [fill=black] (-3,0) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw[color=black] (-4.0,0.30) node {$C(-3 , 0)$};
    \draw [fill=black] (0,-3) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw[color=black] (1,-3.40) node {$D(0 , -3)$};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: lines seem disappear behind the color

Comment: @snehal i just updated my answer

Comment: Whatever you mention under Edit: i can't understand. Could you please explain?

Comment: In answer given by jak123 out put looks very clear i mean color which filled in region such a way that both lines and curve look clear

Comment: @snehal I added some explanations, did I explain it well?

Comment: Now it is clear. Billions thanks for providing useful information. I am improving my knowledge of drawing day by day through these kind of help.

Answer (score 7):

Here for comparison is a version made with [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html).

[image]

I've tried to avoid "duplication" by defining the circle as a `path` variable, and then referring to arcs along the circle using `subpath` and points around it using `point x of y`.  In MP there are 8 points around the predefined path `fullcircle`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    color shade[];
    shade[0] = 1/256 (215,25,28);
    shade[1] = 1/256 (253,174,97);
    shade[2] = 1/256 (171,221,164);
    shade[3] = 1/256 (43,131,186);

    path C, xx, yy; 
    C = fullcircle scaled 6cm;
    xx = (left--right) scaled 4cm;
    yy = xx rotated 90;

    for i=0 upto 3:
        fill origin -- subpath (2i, 2i+2) of C -- cycle withcolor 1/2[shade[i], white];
    endfor

    draw C;
    drawdblarrow xx;
    drawdblarrow yy;

    dotlabel.urt ("$O(0,0)$", center C);
    dotlabel.urt ("$A(3,0)$", point 0 of C);
    dotlabel.urt ("$B(0,3)$", point 2 of C);
    dotlabel.ulft("$C(-3,0)$", point 4 of C);
    dotlabel.lrt ("$D(0,-3)$", point 6 of C);

    label.ulft("$x^2+y^2=9$", point 3 of C);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Compile with `lualatex`.

Comment: I really like your colors!

Comment: @Aditya Thank you, but the credit should really go to Cynthia Brewer.  They are "Spectral4" from http://colorbrewer2.org, mixed with 50% white.  For my MP implementation of colorbrewer see https://ctan.org/pkg/metapost-colorbrewer

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,scale=.9,x=1cm,y=1cm]
    \begin{axis}[
    x=1cm,y=1cm,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={stealth-stealth},
    xmin=-5,
    xmax=5,
    ymin=-5,
    ymax=5.0,
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick=\empty,]
    \draw[fill=cyan, line width= 0] (0,0) -- (3,0) arc (0:90:3cm) -- (0,0);
    \draw[fill=magenta, line width= 0] (0,0) -- (0,3) arc (90:180:3cm) -- (0,0);
    \draw[fill=yellow, line width= 0] (0,0) -- (-3,0) arc (180:270:3cm) -- (0,0);
    \draw[fill=black, line width= 0] (0,0) -- (0,-3) arc (270:360:3cm) -- (0,0);
    \draw [line width=0.8pt,color=black] (0,0) circle (3cm);
    %Labelling of endpoints and curve
    \draw[color=black] (-3.0,3.0) node {$x^2+y^2=9$};
    \draw [fill=black] (0,0) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw[color=black] (0.8,-0.6) node {$O(0 , 0)$};
    \draw [fill=black] (3,0) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw[color=black] (3.8,0.4) node {$A(3 , 0)$};
    \draw [fill=black] (0,3) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw[color=black] (0.70,3.40) node {$B(0 ,3)$};
    \draw [fill=black] (-3,0) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw[color=black] (-4.0,0.30) node {$C(-3 , 0)$};
    \draw [fill=black] (0,-3) circle (2.5pt);
    \draw[color=black] (1,-3.40) node {$D(0 , -3)$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another TikZ solution, very minimalist, using `foreach` and polar coordinates (I love polar coordinates):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \a/\c in {0/orange,90/blue,180/green,270/pink}{
  \fill[\c] (0,0) -- (\a:3) arc (\a:\a+90:3) -- cycle;
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

No PSTricks, no party!

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-4.5,-4.5)(5,5)
    \psaxes[ticks=none,labels=none]{->}(0,0)(-4.5,-4.5)(4.5,4.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \foreach \i/\c  in {0/red,90/green,180/blue,270/yellow}
        {\pswedge[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=\c!50]{3}{\i}{!\i\space 90 add}}
    \foreach \i/\j/\k in {{0,0}/45/{O(0,0)},{3,0}/45/{A(r,0)},{0,3}/45/{B(0,r)},{-3,0}/135/{C(-r,0)},{0,-3}/225/{D(0,-r)}}
        {\qdisk(\i){2pt}\uput{3pt}[\j](\i){$\k$}}
    \uput{3pt}[135](3;135){$x^2+y^2=9$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Without Labels

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\degrees[100]
\begin{document}
\pspicture(-4,-4)(4,4)
\foreach \i  in {25,50,75,100}{\pswedge*[linecolor=red!\i]{3}{\i}{!\i\space 25 add}}
\endpspicture
\end{document}
```

[image]