# Domains with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I'm trying to reproduce this

[image: domains]

What I was able to do :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1] 
\def \rayon{2};
\def \i{40};
\def \r{25.4}; 

\draw (0,0) circle (\rayon); 
\draw[dotted](0,\rayon)--++(0,-2*\rayon); 
\draw[dotted](-\rayon,0)--++(2*\rayon,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please edit your code to only include those packages necessary for your example.

Comment: You can add a second circle just like you did the first and add `fill=red` as an option. Put this after the first circle and before you draw the dotted lines so the lines go over the top.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inspired by the comments above -- should help the OP in his pursuit

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1] 
        \def \rayon{2};
        \def \i{40};
        \def \r{25.4}; 
        
        \coordinate[label=90:{text}](name) at (0, \rayon ex);
        \draw (0,0) circle (\rayon); 
        \draw[fill=red]  (0,0) circle(\rayon/5); 
        \draw[dotted](0,\rayon) node[above]{1}--++(0,-2*\rayon) node[below]{1}; 
        \draw[dotted](-\rayon,0)--++(2*\rayon,0); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

The top part of the circle has a different color

Simply add the following line to your code

```
    \draw[fill=cyan, line width= 0] (0,0) -- (\rayon,0) arc (0:180:\rayon) -- (0,0);
```

Have a look at this answer

[Fill all four quadrants of a circle with different colors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457482/fill-all-four-quadrants-of-a-circle-with-different-colors)

**Complete MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1] 
        \def \rayon{2};
        \def \i{40};
        \def \r{25.4}; 
        
        \draw[fill=cyan, line width= 0] (0,0) -- (\rayon,0) arc (0:180:\rayon) -- (0,0);
        
        \coordinate[label=90:{text}](name) at (0, \rayon ex);
        \draw (0,0) circle (\rayon); 
        \draw[fill=red]  (0,0) circle(\rayon/5); 
        \draw[dotted](0,\rayon) node[above]{1}--++(0,-2*\rayon) node[below]{1}; 
        \draw[dotted](-\rayon,0)--++(2*\rayon,0); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: How can I put a color on the north domain ?

Comment: @Fractal please see the edit to the answer and link here --https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457482/fill-all-four-quadrants-of-a-circle-with-different-colors

Comment: @Fractal, it's always a good idea to spend some time again on the pgfmanual, e.g. on filling: https://tikz.dev/tutorial#autosec-96 .